# Not getting required result while reading a text file in Python 3.8.1

Tags: python-3.x, file

- I have a text file named 'text1.txt'.
- Contents of file are just one line - Sueña el r

I read the file in Python as under:

```
f = open('text1.txt')
f.seek(3)
print(f.read(1)) # Ã
f.close()
```

My question is - **Why am I getting Ã instead of ñ ?**
Is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: how about open('text1.txt','rb')?

Comment: The result is b'\xc3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read string with utf-8 encoding:

```
f = open('123.txt', encoding="utf-8")
```

output:

```
>>> ñ
```

Answer (score 0):

store it as an variable

```
str = 'Sueña el r'
```

then use print

```
print(str[3])
```

works the same and gives the correct answer